# Adding a Circular TextView or Button on top of a Divider on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in android. In one of my view I need to add a circular TextView or Button on top a divider view? The button need to be centered horizontally and vertically on top of divider. How can I do that like following? I have search many sources but didn't find exact thing. Can any one please help me do that?

[image: button top of divider]

I create the divider following way:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/aaa"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_2sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/gradient_divider" />
```

and style looks like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#e5eaff"
        android:startColor="#f3f5f9" />

</shape>
```

Comment: you want a circular button and below that the image view?

Comment: on top of the imageview which should be  centered horizontally and vertically

Comment: can u explain exactly what you want any blueprint image to show up to design your ui?

Comment: I have updated the image

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below code:

shape_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#ffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2222"/>
</shape>
```

shape_line.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
    <size android:height="2dp" />
</shape>
```

And use it in `ConstraintLayout` like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/with_layer"/>

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="OR"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hey buddy, I have edited your answer please have a look if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes. that worked after some adjusting. Would be better if you share a method for linear layout.